# Composable does not update when mutablestateflow in viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I have Viewmodel where I keep reference to post. When i want to translate post i run function to update state flow and post and if I put logs there I see that value is changed but my composable did not get any new value. Here is part of code from viewmodel that doing this magic

```
    private var originalText = tile.text?.originalText
    private var text = tile.text?.text

    private var _postTileState = MutableStateFlow(tile)
    val tileState = _postTileState.asStateFlow()

    fun translateText() {
        val newText = if (_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated == true)
            originalText
        else text
        val postText = PostText(
            text = newText,
            isTranslated = !_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated!!,
            originalText = tile.text?.originalText
        )
        _postTileState.value.text = postText
    }
```

Tile here is one post. And here is parent composable

```
@Composable
fun PostTileView(
    tile: PostTile,
    content: @Composable (
        tile: PostTile,
    ) -> Unit
) {
    val postTileViewModel = postTileViewModel(
        tile,
        id = tile.id
    )
    val postTile = postTileViewModel.tileState.collectAsState().value

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Style.colors.content)
            .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
    ) {
        PostTileHeaderView(postTile.author, createdDate = postTile.createdDate)
        content(postTile)
        if(postTile.text?.originalText != null) {
            Button(onClick = {
                postTileViewModel.translateText()
            }) {
                val buttonTitle = if(postTile.text!!.isTranslated == true)
                    "Show original" else "Translate"
                Text(text = buttonTitle)
            }
        }
        PostTags(tags = postTile.tags)
    }
}
```

If i put some other state with this one in viewmodel like some boolean and get reference to it in composable it works fine but with updating post it does not work. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `translateText()` function, you can't update just a single variable of the object inside the state flow like that `_postTileState.value.text = postText`, but instead you need to update the hole object so your function should look like that:

```
fun translateText() {
    val newText = if (_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated == true)
        originalText
    else text
    val postText = PostText(
        text = newText,
        isTranslated = !_postTileState.value.text?.isTranslated!!,
        originalText = tile.text?.originalText
    )
    _postTileState.value = _postTileState.value.copy(text = postText)
}
```

Now the state flow will notice that you set a new object.

Comment: Nah i found problem also. PostTile is Interface not data class. I used interface as I have super type Tile that is class, then have Interface PostTile and all other tiles like MediaTile, QuestionTile inherit from both PostTile and Tile. I need to find way to declare PostTile as data class to be able to have copy method on it :(

Comment: All the states should be data classes, that's the recommended type. I think that you should change states to data classes, this is not what the interfaces were made for

Comment: Or you can create a data class that extends that interface.